# Regex validation with WTForms and python

Tags: python, regex, wtforms

Here is my code:

```
class CreateUser(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', [
        validators.Regexp('\w+', message="Username must contain only letters numbers or underscore"),
        validators.Length(min=5, max=25, message="Username must be betwen 5 & 25 characters")

    ])

    password = PasswordField('New Password', [
        validators.DataRequired(), 
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')
    ])

    confirm  = PasswordField('Repeat Password')
```

So the problem exists at line 3. I want the username to be only alpha numeric characters. For some reason this regex is only checking the first character. Is there a reason why the + symbol is not working here? Thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, '\w+' means "one or more of the character \w", i think you want r'\w+' to prevent escaping

Comment: @user2085282 yeah that doesn\t work either. but i think it likely has something to do with escaping...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Replacing the regex with

```
'^\w+$'
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was answered a long time ago, but another option I discovered to provide alphanumeric validation on WTForms is AlphaNumeric()

```
from wtforms_validators import AlphaNumeric
...

class SignupForm(Form):
    login_id = StringField('login Id', [DataRequired(), AlphaNumeric()])
```

More details here https://pypi.org/project/wtforms-validators/

Answer (score 0):

@mpn solution works fine but I was wondering why `\w+` is not matching the whole string.

In wtforms' [Regexp class](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/_modules/wtforms/validators/#Regexp) whitin the method `__call__` you will see that `self.regex.match(field.data or '')` will be called. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) of re.py states about `re.match` that:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
> regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.

Hence, we will have to use `^` to match the start of the string and `$` to match the end of the string. Read more about the special characters in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).